# Want to decorate email sending with new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I am stuck on decorating the function.
Help me find out the problem.
Decorator:

```
def sync(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thr = Thread(target=f, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thr.start()
    return wrapper
```

Sending functions:

```
def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
    """ Build and send e-mail with the provided parameters."""

    msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    mail.send(msg)

@sync
def send_confirmation_email(recipient, app = current_app):
    """Send registration email to the provided recipient."""

    subject = 'Account confirmation e-mail'
    sender = 'some.mail.for.testing@domain.com'
    recipients = [recipient]
    activation, deletion = confirmation_links(recipient) #construct hashed links
    text_body = render_template('confirmation_email.txt',
                            activation = activation,
                            deletion = deletion)
    html_body = render_template('confirmation_email.html',
                            activation = activation,
                            deletion = deletion)
    send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body)
```

Views function:

```
@app.route('/signup', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    form = SignupForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        send_confirmation_email(recipient = form.email.data)
        return redirect(url_for('activate'))
    else:
        return render_template('signup.html',
                       title = 'Sign Up',
                       form = form)
```

The problem is that emails are not sent with active decorator `@sync`.
When I remove `@sync` decorator everything is working but, of course, without threading.
And `app` waits a few seconds before `redirect`.
Any help will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Do it with Celery instead.. It is a way more correct way to handle such a problem.. https://github.com/mattupstate/overholt is a great example

Comment: @brunsgaard, thanks for the link. It is a little app I am creating, and threading is used just once. And I agree that Celery is a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `render_template` function requires a [Flask application context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/) to work.

When your `send_confirmation_email` function is run in a seperate thread there is no application context set up for `render_template` to work.

You could solve this by using `app.app_context()`:

```
@sync
def send_confirmation_email(recipient):
    """Send registration email to the provided recipient."""

    with app.app_context():
        subject = 'Account confirmation e-mail'
        sender = 'some.mail.for.testing@domain.com'
        recipients = [recipient]
        activation, deletion = confirmation_links(recipient) #construct hashed links
        text_body = render_template('confirmation_email.txt',
                                activation = activation,
                                deletion = deletion)
        html_body = render_template('confirmation_email.html',
                                activation = activation,
                                deletion = deletion)
        send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body)
```

You could also look into using something like [Celery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/)

Comment: Actually, something was wrong with implementing your answer in my `app`. Mails was not sent. Finally, I managed to resolve the problem by creating a function which takes just msg(message) and sends it and call a sync decorator on it. `app.app_context()` was not used by me but the info and help were very valuable. +1